# How to categories each pairing 2D Coordinate which is linking to each other in python?

Tags: python, arrays, duplicates

I have pairs of 2D-coordinate (x,y) in each array. But I need to categorize it into "duplicate linking relationships".

```
locArray = [[(1134, 604), (1134, 605)], [(1135, 604), (1135, 605)], [(1134, 605), (1135, 605)], [(1135, 605), (1134, 605)], [(1136, 605), (1135, 605)], [(1135, 606), (1135, 605)], [(1153, 921), (1153, 922)], [(1154, 921), (1153, 921)], [(1153, 922), (1153, 921)]]
```

The final output should be:

```
categorizedArray = [[(1134, 604), (1135, 604), (1134, 605), (1135, 605), (1136, 605), (1135, 606)], [(1153, 921), (1154, 921), (1153, 922)]]
```

which does not have any duplicated values.

Comment: That only can remove duplicates but is not able to categorize/group the arrays. Please do note that there are 9 pairing groups of the array at first. And then, those arrays that have the same similarities are grouped together. We can notice there are 2 groups in the final output.

Comment: For example, Jan with Feb, Mar with Feb, Apr with May, Apr with June, July with Feb. The final output will be [[Jan, Feb, Mar, July], [Apr, May, June]]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this script based on your comment using months. If you didn't gave another example it would be hard to understand what you wanted to do with `locArray`.

```
locArray = [
    [(1134, 604), (1134, 605)], # 0
    [(1135, 604), (1135, 605)], # 1
    [(1134, 605), (1135, 605)], # 2
    [(1135, 605), (1134, 605)], # 3
    [(1136, 605), (1135, 605)], # 4
    [(1135, 606), (1135, 605)], # 5
    [(1153, 921), (1153, 922)], # 6
    [(1154, 921), (1153, 921)], # 7
    [(1153, 922), (1153, 921)]  # 8
]

# pairs is an array of pairs: [(x, y), ..., (x, y)]
#
# It checks if, from coord z is inside
# any of the pairs from the pairs array.
def coordInside(pairs, coord):
    for pair in pairs:
        if (coord == pair[0] or coord == pair[1]):
            return True
    return False

# Seeks out for every created category, from pair (a, b),
# if a or b is listed inside any category array.
#
# If no category is found, return -1
def findCategory(categories, pair):
    index = 0
    for category in categories:
        if (coordInside(category, pair[0]) or coordInside(category, pair[1])):
            return index
        index += 1
    return -1

# Categorizes by column order: [0, 1] all x-coordinates, then all y-coordinates.
def categorizeByColumns(array, cols=[0]):
    categories = []

    # For every column
    for col in cols:

        # For every row of the array:
        for row in array:

            # Retrieve the pair from the current row and column
            pair = row[col]

            # Get the current Category
            index = findCategory(categories, pair)

            # If no Category exists
            if (index == -1):
                # Create one and append to categories array
                categories.append([pair])

            # If the Category exists, append pair given it's not a duplicate
            elif (pair not in categories[index]):
                categories[index].append(pair)

    return categories

# Generates the desired output you want
print(categorizeByColumns(locArray, [0, 1]))
```

This is the output: `[[(1134, 604), (1135, 604), (1134, 605), (1135, 605), (1136, 605), (1135, 606)], [(1153, 921), (1154, 921), (1153, 922)]]`